# Echo MySQL column values on screen

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm creating a friends system for my site, and I've created a table showing their relationships.

I have three columns: 'friend_id','friender','friendee'. Friend_ID is just a unique id for the relationship, Friender is the person that requested the friendship, and friendee is the person who accepted the friendship.

[image: Table]

I want to be able to echo the ID's of all the friends of any particular user. So if I chose user 1, it would return 10, 8, 2, and 6

All it takes is on simple SQL query:

```
SELECT friender FROM friends WHERE friendee = '1' UNION SELECT friendee FROM friends WHERE friender = '1'
```

The query returns values 10, 8, 2, and 6

What's the best way to echo these values onto the screen? I would think you have to put them in an array and use a foreach loop, but I'm not sure. I'm new to backend development and it would be extremely helpful to get an answer.

This is what I've tried:
    $sql = "SELECT friendee FROM friends WHERE friender = '1'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

```
            $storeArray = Array();

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $storeArray[] =  $row['friendee'];
                foreach($storeArray as $item) {
                    echo $item.', ';
                }

                echo $storeArray[0].', '.$storeArray[1];
            }
```

Comment: Well you show us what you have done so far and we will suggest corrections. However SO **is not a free coding service**

Comment: `echo $value`, of course...

Comment: If you're in PHP you're going to want to decide which MySQL API to use before you do anything else here.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Alright.  Well how far have you gotten?  Do you have a working connection to the database?  Etc.?

Comment: Yes, I have a connection to the database and a mysqli query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mysqli_fetch_array() to get the results from you query to prepare to loop through them.

This is some good information on this function here as well as some examples. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Also it should be noted that you can turn those two queries into one with a UNION.  SELECT friender AS friend FROM friends WHERE friendee = '1' UNION SELECT friendee AS friend FROM friends WHERE friender = '1' is a single statement that will return the data in a column named "friend".

Comment: But then you won't know which row is which. Better to select both columns and use a WHERE: `SELECT friendee, friender FROM friends WHERE  friendee = '1' OR friender = '1'`

Comment: He didn't seem to care which is which, just that they were friends.  But yeah if you need to know which is which you can do it that way too.